# My carousel not working. Think it's the "link-rel" in the head tag

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

My carousel isn't working (not navigating). 
Console shows:

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for
>   resource
>   'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'
>   with computed SHA-256 integrity
>   'YLGeXaapI0/5IgZopewRJcFXomhRMlYYjugPLSyNjTY='. The resource has been
>   blocked.

I tried replacing that line in my code but then the carousel got all messed up and it didn't exactly fixed it...

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the head tag because it worked a while ago.
Didn't find any solution for it...

How can I fix it? and for good... not temporarily...
I need a code that'll work at all times.

here is my `<head>` tag:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Style/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<link href="styles/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="jScripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="jScripts/JavaScript.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with the integrity of the link you used to get bootstrap's CSS - to resolve, **change your existing CDN path from**:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">`

**To** the one rec[ommended on Bootstrap's website](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) :
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">`

working **snippet** below:

```css
/* Make the image fully responsive */

.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <link href="Style/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />


  <link href="styles/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Assistant" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="jScripts/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script src="jScripts/JavaScript.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


  <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Any errors on the console? Is the snippet working for you?